# Which event will be fired after inner html has completely rendered in DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular

I want to know what event will be fired when the `innerHtml` property of any `div` is changed and DOM the tree for that `div` is completely loaded into memory.

I want to invoke the following function after that event is fired. I want to remove the `setTimeout()` hack in the following function as it may fail sometime.

```
private registerEventListenersForLink() {
  let _self = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var AElemList = document.querySelectorAll('.appmedia-content-wrapper a');
    for (let i = 0; i < AElemList.length; i++) {
      AElemList[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var url = event.target["href"];
        if (url && url.trim() != '') {
          _self.utilService.openUrlExternaly(url);
        }
      });
    }
  }, 80);
}
```

I have found following links related to above issue but I haven't got any ideas out of it:

[Event to determine when innerHTML has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001376/event-to-determine-when-innerhtml-has-loaded)

https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/apis-in-html-documents.html#dom-innerhtml

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:angularjs] and [tag:angular2]?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead of an event handler.

Comment: As it's marked jquery:  `$(function() { ... code to run when DOM ready ... });`

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan but I want this code to be functional in android Webview because I am developing a cross platform mobile app. How can I make code compatible in old browsers with using  MutationObserver?

Comment: If you need legacy browser support then MutationObserver isn't going to work unfortunately. Your alternatives are to constantly poll the DOM (which is what you're currently doing), which is unsightly and can cause slowdown. Or you could manually raise an event when an element is changed, but this will only work if you have control of the codebase. If it's a third party library adding content you cannot do this and the first method is all that's available to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue. I have implemented a directive as follows and it has worked like a charm. Thank you  Rory McCrossan for pointing me at MutationObserver api.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilService } from '../../providers/util-service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[external-links]' // Attribute selector
})
export class ExternalLinks {
  private observer;
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, public utilService: UtilService) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var _self = this;
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
          var AElemList = _self.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
          for (let i = 0; i < AElemList.length; i++) {
            AElemList[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
              var url = event.target["href"];
              if (url && url.trim() != '') {
                _self.utilService.openUrlExternaly(url);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
    var config = { childList: true };

    this.observer.observe(this.elRef.nativeElement, config);
  }

}
```