# Start a function when innerHTML has fully loaded in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, svg

I was wondering if in Angular, it is possible to get informed when Inner HTML has been fully loaded.
I have a web application that fetches a SVG-Image from a server. I need to show it as innerHTML because I need to perform actions on the svg and also call component functions from it.
After loading it from the server I have to do some small changes to the SVG and therefore wait untill it is completely loaded in the innerHTML. At the moment I add a picture at the end of the SVG and call the function where I perform the changes on the SVG like this:

`<img onload="smallSVGChanges(); this.parent.removeChild(this)">`

But I'm pretty sure that this is not he best way to do it.

I have found a related question to this problem, but I don't think that my question is a complete duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001376/event-to-determine-when-innerhtml-has-loaded#:%7E:text=getElementById(%22Testing%22).,your%20innerHTML%20has%20been%20loaded.), because it is almost 10 years old and no angular was used there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this `<img (onload)="doSomethingOnComponent()">` and define the function `doSomethingOnComponent` inside the component definition in the corresponding typescript file.

Comment: Ok but than there is no better way than adding an image? Nothing like a onload in the container of the inner-HTML? Thx btw

Comment: I didn't understand. Do you want to call your function on `onload` but not really load the image? Do you want an event that is fired when innerHTML changed?

Comment: I want to call a function when the svg has been fully loaded in the innerHTML. Currently I use the trick to with the image. I add it at the end of the function and when it's loaded I call the function with onload on the image. But I don't think this can be the best way to check when the innerHTML has been fully loaded.

Comment: Our capabilities are bounded on what you can do with pure JavaScript. If you can't do a thing with JavaScript, you can't do it with angular, react, whatever... They are just built on top of what JavaScript provides. So I think you cannot.